# Sending cookies with websockets using Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I'm currently connecting to websockets using tornado, is there a way I can pass along a cookie with the websocket connection?

```
import logging

import tornado.httpclient
import tornado.gen
import tornado.options
import tornado.web
import tornado.websocket

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def connect_websocket():

    url = tornado.options.options.ws_host

    try:
        ws_connection = yield tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(url, connect_timeout=5)
        logging.info("Connection established (%s), waiting for output...", url)
    except Exception as conn_err:
        logging.error("Error connecting to %s", conn_err)
        return

    while True:
        output = yield ws_connection.read_message()
        logging.info(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.options.define(name="ws_host", type=str, help="Websocket host address.")
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().run_sync(connect_websocket)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `url` parameter in `websocket_connect(url)` can be a plain URL string but it can also be a [`tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest) object. Although, it's not documented but you can see this in the [source code](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/websocket.py#L1229).

So, you can create an instance of `HTTPRequest` and set the Cookie header there, after all, cookie is just a header.

Example:

```
from tornado import httpclient

# create an instace of HTTPRequest with the given url
request = httpclient.HTTPRequest(url, headers={'Cookie': 'name=value'})

# connect to ws using the request object
ws_connection = yield tornado.websocket.websocket_connect(request)
```